# Is there a way to get Lualatex to ignore metadata for embedded graphics?

Tags: pdftex, luatex

I have moved over from pdflatex to lualatex and in the process, it seems like I am only able to embed some pdf documents and not others.

When I try to embed graphics with lualatex, I get `(pdf inclusion): reading image failed` error.

I later found that when using a [preflight](https://freetoolonline.com/preflight-pdf.html) tool on the above document, which detected an issue with `7.1: Error on MetaData, Failed to instanciate property in xmp:CreateDate`. Removing all the metadata from the document and then trying again, then it worked.

Is there a way for Lualatex to ignore these and still embed the graphics so I don't have to remove all metadata before I embed them?

Comment: you are jumping to conclusion. It is quite unclear which error in your pdf made lualatex fail--- it is quite possible that removing the metadata (how did you do it?) simply corrected also the other errors. For me your file worked after I simply opened it in adobe reader and saved it under a new name.

Comment: I used Exiftool to remove the metadata. What would have changed by opening it and saving it under a new name? Other than the name of course.

Comment: @DanMaia If the program you use for saving it conforms to the PDF specification, then the saved file should never contain any errors. So there is a good chance that any errors which existed in the original file which were not fatal while loading it will not be written into the file again.

Comment: well the size changed from 2800 to 2200, so adobe reader seems to clean up and compress and probably this repairs your pdf. You can also try with ghostscript, it has a pdfwriter too.

Comment: I see, has Luatex documented that it expects PDF to conform to the specification? I guess that's a given as it should anyway.

Comment: if a PDF doesn't conform then what happened is undefined, some pdf viewer and tools recover, other don't.

Comment: So in this case, Lualatex just fails instead of fixing it like other tools. How come I didn't get this issue with Pdflatex? Does that fix it then?

Comment: neither pdflatex nor lualatex *fix* a pdf. They parse and include it. And if it has a fault, it can make them fail. Complain to the producer of your pdf. At least the value for /Trapped is plainly wrong.

Comment: "Value for /Trapped is plainly wrong"? What do you mean? I will definitely complain to the producer of the PDF. I am struggling to understand why it worked for one engine (pdflatex) but not lualatex.

Comment: why is that hard to understand? If the file is badly formed then it is not PDF so if you include it as PDF what happens is undefined. If it happens to accidentally work in pdftex and it happens to error in luatex then that is totally consistent with "the behaviour is undefined"

Comment: They use `/Trapped (False)`, the correct syntax is `/Trapped /False`.

Comment: I think an even bigger issue than the wrong `/Trapped` syntax is the wrong type in the trailer. It contains `/Length 174 /Type /XRef /Filter /FlateDecode`. Neither entry is allowed there or makes any sense.